# How to prevent IBM i from changing the library of an external stored-procedure when moving external program to a different library

Tags: ibm-midrange

I've noticed that the IBM i will automatically change the library of an external stored-procedure to match the library of the external program when the program is moved.  Is there a way to stop that?

For example:

1. Let's say that I've this RPGLE program => MYLIB1/TESTRP.
2. I used below to create an external stored-procedure for it:

   ```
      CREATE PROCEDURE MYLIB1/TESTSP() Language RPGLE External name TESTRP
   ```
3. Using query below, I can see that the stored procedure is being created under library MYLIB1 (SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = 'MYLIB1').

   ```
    SELECT * FROM QSYS2/SYSPROCS WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME LIKE 'TESTSP'
   ```
4. Now, use command below to move the TESTRP program from library MYLIB1 to  MYLIB2:

   ```
    MOVOBJ OBJ(MYLIB1/TESTRP) OBJTYPE(*PGM) TOLIB(MYLIB2)
   ```
5. Using the same query on step3, I see that IBMi automatically moved the Stored Procedure to from MYLIB1 to MYLIB2 (SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = 'MYLIB2').  Is there a way to prevent this?  I want the stored procedure to stay in MYLIB1.

Comment: Do you mean CREATE PROCEDURE MYLIB1/TESTSP() Language RPGLE External name MYLIB2/TESTRP?

Comment: no, I don't want to hard code the library of TESTRP.  I want the stored procedure to get the program using *LIBL.  The main issue  I'm having is when I move the TESTRP program from MYLIB1 to MYLIB2.  When this happen, IBMi automatically change the stored procedure from MYLIB1 schema to MYLIB2 schema.  I want the stored procedure to stay in MYLIB1 schema.

Comment: To further explain the problem,  our shop uses a CMS call "Implementer" to migration program changes to production.  Implementer has a feature to archive existing version of program before moving the changes into production library.  So, if I make a change to TESTRP, "Implementer" will do this:  Moves the TESTRP program from production library (MYPRODLIB) to the archive library (ARCHIVELIB), then it moves the new TESTRP into the production library.  This will break the stored procedure.  Because IBMi auto changed it's schema to ARCHIVELIB and ARCHIVELIB is not in our standard production *LIBL.

Comment: I understand that the problem can be solved by recreating the stored procedure back into the MYPRODLIB library.  But it is hard for programmers to remember that.  Most programming changes do not involve changing entry parameters.  So, there is no need to make changes to stored procedure at all, and most of the time programmers do not even realized that the program they are changing is being called from a stored procedure until production website starts to break.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/recommended-stored-procedure-actions
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/stored-procedures-and-object-management

Answer (score 1):

You should open a support case with the vendor.

I suspect there's a way to define the stored proc to your CMS, so that it manages it along with the external program.